# SQL query remove Overlapping Start And EndDates

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have table with Start Date and End Date rows like below.

```
START Date |    END Date
2013-01-01 |    2013-09-30
2013-01-01 |    2013-12-31
2013-10-01 |    2013-12-31
2014-01-01 |    2099-12-31
```

The desired result is

```
START Date |    END Date
2013-01-01 |    2013-09-30
2013-10-01 |    2013-12-31
2014-01-01 |    2099-12-31
```

I need a query to remove duplicate row with overlapping dates. The query needs to retain rows that have small date range, in the example above the query should remove row with Start Date 1/1/2013 and end date 12/31/2013.

I am using SQL Server 2008. Recursive CTE, `row_number()` functions can be used to write the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with cte
As
(
Select Row_Number() Over(Partition By [Start DATE]
                         Order By Datediff(dd,[Start Date],[End Date]) Asc
) as RNo, [Start Date], [End Date]  from yourtablename )
Select [Start Date],[End Date] from Cte where RNo =1;
```